# Badge Progress Percentage

Tags: support, badges

I definitely saw a list of some badges and how far through completing them I was. Now I can't find it.

Where on my profile is that list?

It was on the right hand side of the screen. And it had like 0% complete for the badges at the top, and 80% for the ones near the bottom.

How do I see that again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you're not referring to [reputation privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges)?

[image]

Comment: Yes, i meant that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You probably mean the review page; each review "section" has its own progress.

The design was recently changed though, it's no longer to the right. Now it's on top and initially appears as a progress bar:

> [image]

Hovering over the bar will show the full progress towards more badges:

> [image]